# Cannot turn on LG GT540 due to kernel panic

Tags: kernel, lg-gt540-optimus

I cannot turn on my LG GT540. When I try to turn it on it displays a message which says:

```
Linux Kernel Panic Process swapper (pid : 1 )
```

What does this mean? How can I fix it?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_panic - as for fixing it I'm not sure.

Comment: Perhaps you could have a look on http://www.askmefast.com/How_to_fix_Kernal_Panic_on_Android_Tablet-qna1605276.html for some fixes people have tried.

Comment: Which ROM are you using? Can you get to recovery?